# Populate third drop down menu based on first & second menu selection

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the following code to dynamically populate three drop down menus "project_select", "hr_select", and "id_select".

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example1').DataTable({
    data: dataSet1,
    orderCellsTop: true,
    columns: [{
        data: "Project_Name"
      },
      {
        data: "ID"
      },
      {
        data: "HR"
      }
    ],
    initComplete: function() {
      this.api().columns([0, 1, 2]).every(function() {
        var column = this;
        var colIdx = column.index();
        var node;
        var select;
        if (colIdx === 0) {
          node = $('#project_select');
          select = $('<select id="project_s" style="width: 20%"><option value=""></option></select>');
        }
        if (colIdx === 2) {
          node = $('#hr_select');
          select = $('<select id="hr_s" style="width: 20%" multiple><option value=""></option></select>');
        }
        if (colIdx === 1) {
          node = $('#id_select');
          select = $('<select id="id_s" style="width: 20%" multiple><option value=""></option></select>');

        }

        select.appendTo($(node).empty())
          .on('change', function() {
            var val = $(this).val();
            if (colIdx === 0) {
              val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(val);
              column.search(val).draw();
              rebuildPositionSelect();
              rebuildIDSelect();
            }
            if (colIdx === 2) {
              const vals = $('option:selected', this).map(function(index, element) {
                return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());
              }).toArray().join('|');
              column.search(vals.length > 0 ? '^(' + vals + ')$' : '', true, false).draw();
              rebuildIDSelect();
            } else {
              const vals = $('option:selected', this).map(function(index, element) {
                return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());
              }).toArray().join('|');
              column.search(vals.length > 0 ? '^(' + vals + ')$' : '', true, false).draw();
            }
          });

        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(val) {
          select.append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>')
        });

      });


      function rebuildPositionSelect() {
        var select = $('#hr_select select').empty().append('<option value=""></option>');
        var column = table.column(2, {
          search: 'applied'
        });
        column.search('').draw();
        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(val) {
          select.append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
        });
      }

      function rebuildIDSelect() {
        var select = $('#id_select select').empty().append('<option value=""></option>');
        var column = table.column(1, {
          search: 'applied'
        });
        column.search('').draw();
        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(val) {
          select.append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
        });
      }

      $('#project_s').select2({
        placeholder: "Select Project:",
        allowClear: true,
        width: 'resolve'
      })
      $('#hr_s').select2({
        placeholder: "Select Hr(s):",
        closeOnSelect: false,
        allowClear: true,
        tags: true,
        width: 'resolve'
      });
      $('#id_s').select2({
        placeholder: "Select ID:",
        closeOnSelect: false,
        allowClear: true,
        tags: true,
        width: 'resolve'
      });


    }
  });

});
```

Currently, the "hr_select" and "id_select" menus populate with values based on the user's single selection within "project_select". I am struggling to further populate the "id_select" menu based on the user's multiple selections within "hr_select".

Example of error: The user selects Project A and Hours 0, 10, 20. The "id_select" menu should ONLY populate with the value "Spike". The menu is currently populating with the values of "Spike" and "Hit".

Any ideas on how to fix my function `rebuildIDSelect` to fix this error?

https://jsfiddle.net/dfahsjdahfsudaf/nL6q21g9/63/

Thanks.

Edit: The "id_select" menu should only populate with the value Spike because when you filter the overall data table for Project A and Hours 0,10,20.. Spike is the only value in the table that is listed for all those values. Hit is only associated with Project A and Hours 0, 10. Because Hit is not listed as a row in the table for Hour 20.. it should not show up in the "id_select" menu when a user selected Hours 0,10,and 20 from "hr_select" menu.

Comment: Can you clarify the reason _why_ the "id_select" menu should ONLY populate with the value "Spike" in your example? What is the rule you are using?

Comment: @andrewJames I have edited my question to answer your question. I hope my answer make sense.

Answer (score 0):

What the logic is asking for is the intersection of the ID values based on the selected HR values. That is quite a lot more complicated than just using `0 or 10 or 20` because it requires you to take account of data across the entire column.

The following approach is not a full solution - there is at least one issue which I will mention at the end. Also, I suspect there may be a more efficient way to implement the following, but this should show you one approach:

1. Build an object which shows the set of ID values for each combination of Project and HR value.

Here is the code to do that (using the sample code from your Fiddle):

```js
hrToIdMapper = {};

// builds an object which uses HR for the keys and 
// an array of IDs for each HR:
this.api().rows().every(function() {
  var row = this;
  let key = row.data().Project_Name + '-' + row.data().HR;
  let val = row.data().ID;
  if ( hrToIdMapper.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
    // could be optimized to avoid array duplicates:
    hrToIdMapper[key].push( val ); 
  } else {
    hrToIdMapper[key] = [ val ];
  }
});
```

The data created by this is:

```js
{
  "A-0": [ "Hit", "Spike" ],
  "A-10": [ "Hit", "Spike" ],
  "A-20": [ "Spike" ],
  "B-0": [ "Kick" ],
  "B-10": [ "Kick" ],
  "B-20": [ "Kick" ]
}
```

We will use this data later on to help determine the correct intersection of results we need.

2. Add logic to the `if (colIdx === 2)` section to build an array of selected values.

The logic:

```js
const intersectInputs = $('option:selected', this).map(function(index, element) {
  return $(element).val();
}).toArray().map(x => proj + '-' + x);
```

So, for example, if you have selected Project = "A" and HR = "0, 10, 20", then the array will be as follows:

```js
[ "A-0", "A-10", "A-20" ]
```

This is basically an array of keys which we can see in the data structure we created in step 1.

3. Use the two data structures shown above to build the "intersection results" we need:

```js
function buildIntersection(vals) {
  var arrs = [];

  vals.forEach((val) => { 
    arrs.push( hrToIdMapper[val] );
  } );

  // iterate over each array:
  var results = arrs.reduce(function(prev, curr, idx, arr) {
    // find the overall intersection across all these arrays:
    return prev.filter(value => curr.includes(value))
  });

  return results;
}
```

This takes our array of data from step 2 and for each item in that array, it locates the relevant "Hit/Spike/Kick" array from step 1.

For each of these "Hit/Spike/Kick" arrays, it then finds the intersection (i.e. those values which exist in *all* the "Hit/Spike/Kick" arrays.

In my example, the result is a new array containing only "Spike":

```js
[ "Spike" ]
```

4. We can pass this value to the `rebuildIDSelect()` function, to ensure only the relevant value(s) are displayed in the ID column.

Here is a demo:

```js
var dataSet1 = [{
    "Project_Name": "A",
    "ID": "Hit",
    "HR": "0",
  },
  {
    "Project_Name": "A",
    "ID": "Hit",
    "HR": "10",
  },
  {
    "Project_Name": "A",
    "ID": "Spike",
    "HR": "0",
  },
  {
    "Project_Name": "A",
    "ID": "Spike",
    "HR": "10",
  },
  {
    "Project_Name": "A",
    "ID": "Spike",
    "HR": "20",
  },
  {
    "Project_Name": "B",
    "ID": "Kick",
    "HR": "0",
  },
  {
    "Project_Name": "B",
    "ID": "Kick",
    "HR": "10",
  },
  {
    "Project_Name": "B",
    "ID": "Kick",
    "HR": "20",
  }

];

$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example1').DataTable({
    data: dataSet1,
    orderCellsTop: true,
    columns: [{
        data: "Project_Name"
      },
      {
        data: "ID"
      },
      {
        data: "HR"
      }
    ],
    initComplete: function() {

      hrToIdMapper = {};

      // builds an object which uses HR for the keys and 
      // an array of IDs for each HR:
      this.api().rows().every(function() {
        var row = this;
        let key = row.data().Project_Name + '-' + row.data().HR;
        let val = row.data().ID;
        if ( hrToIdMapper.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
          // could be optimized to avoid array duplicates:
          hrToIdMapper[key].push( val ); 
        } else {
          hrToIdMapper[key] = [ val ];
        }
      });
  
      this.api().columns([0, 1, 2]).every(function() {
        var column = this;
        var colIdx = column.index();
        var node;
        var select;
        if (colIdx === 0) {
          node = $('#project_select');
          select = $('<select id="project_s" style="width: 20%"><option value=""></option></select>');
        }
        if (colIdx === 2) {
          node = $('#hr_select');
          select = $('<select id="hr_s" style="width: 20%" multiple><option value=""></option></select>');
        }
        if (colIdx === 1) {
          node = $('#id_select');
          select = $('<select id="id_s" style="width: 20%" multiple><option value=""></option></select>');

        }

        select.appendTo($(node).empty())
          .on('change', function() {
            var val = $(this).val();
            if (colIdx === 0) {
              val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(val);
              column.search(val).draw();
              rebuildPositionSelect();
              rebuildIDSelect([]);
            }

            if (colIdx === 2) {
              var proj = $("#select2-project_s-container").text();

              const vals = $('option:selected', this).map(function(index, element) {
                return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());
              }).toArray().join('|');
              column.search(vals.length > 0 ? '^(' + vals + ')$' : '', true, false).draw();

              const intersectInputs = $('option:selected', this).map(function(index, element) {
                return $(element).val();
              }).toArray().map(x => proj + '-' + x);
 
             let intersect = buildIntersection(intersectInputs);
             
              rebuildIDSelect(intersect);

            } else {
              const vals = $('option:selected', this).map(function(index, element) {
                return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());
              }).toArray().join('|');
              column.search(vals.length > 0 ? '^(' + vals + ')$' : '', true, false).draw();
            }
          });

        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(val) {
          select.append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>')
        });

      });

      function buildIntersection(vals) {
        var arrs = [];

        vals.forEach((val) => { 
          arrs.push( hrToIdMapper[val] );
        } );

        var results = arrs.reduce(function(prev, curr, idx, arr) {
          return prev.filter(value => curr.includes(value))
        });

        return results;
      }

      function rebuildPositionSelect() {
        var select = $('#hr_select select').empty().append('<option value=""></option>');
        var column = table.column(2, {
          search: 'applied'
        });
        column.search('').draw();
        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(val) {
          select.append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
        });
      }

      function rebuildIDSelect(intersect) {
        var select = $('#id_select select').empty().append('<option value=""></option>');
        var column = table.column(1, { search: 'applied' });
        if (intersect.length === 0) {
          column.search('').draw();
          column.data().unique().sort().each(function(val) {
            select.append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
          });
        } else {
          intersect.forEach((val) => { 
            select.append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
          } );
          column.search('^(' + intersect.join('|') + ')$', true, false).draw();
        }
      }

      $('#project_s').select2({
        placeholder: "Select Project:",
        allowClear: true,
        width: 'resolve'
      })
      $('#hr_s').select2({
        placeholder: "Select Hr(s):",
        closeOnSelect: false,
        allowClear: true,
        tags: true,
        width: 'resolve'
      });
      $('#id_s').select2({
        placeholder: "Select ID:",
        closeOnSelect: false,
        allowClear: true,
        tags: true,
        width: 'resolve'
      });


    }
  });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

     <div style="margin: 20px;">

      <div>
        <span>Project: </span>
        <span id="project_select"></span>
        <span> HR: </span>
        <span id="hr_select"></span>
        <span>ID: </span>
        <span id="id_select"></span>
      </div>

      <br><br>

      <table id="example1" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Project_Name</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>HR</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>


    </div>



  </body>

</html>
```

The end result is this:

[image]

---

**Incomplete Demo**

One remaining issue (there may be more!): Once a user has made their selections and created the end result as shown in the screenshot, the user can choose to select and then delete the "Spike" tag in the ID drop-down. That will currently cause the unwanted "Hit" rows to be re-displayed.

Dealing with edge-cases like this is probably where a lot of additional complexity arises.

A final note which is only my personal opinion: Overall, it may end up being a confusing experience for the user, anyway, if it's not clear *why* they are seeing the results they are seeing. If the drop-down logic gets too complicated, the users may doubt the correctness of what they are seeing.